# Can tikzlings work with equation tag and label?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, tags, tikzlings

\tikz\panda from tikzlings works as a tag for an equation, but if I insert a \label in the equation I get an error. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,american]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzlings-pandas}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pandas}
\begin{equation}\text{The apple-eating Panda}\tag{\tikz\panda[scale=0.15,body=gray];}\label{pandas}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{More Pandas}
As we saw in \eqref{pandas}:
\begin{equation}\text{The not-eating Panda}\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ->\def ;
                         {\tikz@nonactivesemicolon }\def :{\tikz@nonact...
```

Is there some way of making the \label-\eqref mechanism work together with tikzlings as \tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

endangered species must be protected:

```
\documentclass[11pt,american]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzlings-pandas}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pandas}
\begin{equation}\text{The apple-eating Panda}\tag{\protect\tikz\protect\panda[scale=0.15,body=gray];}\label{pandas}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{More Pandas}
As we saw in \eqref{pandas}:
\begin{equation}\text{The not-eating Panda}\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +! for the sentiment in the first sentence.